# Spring Boot: How to tell client that account password has expired?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt

I have a simple login form and a login() method in a controller :

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<UserVO> login(@RequestBody UserVO userVO) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    userVO.getUsername(),
                    userVO.getPassword()
            )
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( authentication );

    // ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok( loggedInUser );
}
```

I have a users table with columns :

```
  `username`
  `password`
  `password_expiration`
  `account_expiration`
  `account_locked`
  `account_disabled`
```

When I set the value of column password_expiration to expire a user's password, Spring Boot's **authenticationManager.authenticate()** method throws an **AccountExpiredException** exception at next login attempt :

```
package org.springframework.security.authentication;

public class AccountExpiredException extends AccountStatusException {
    public AccountExpiredException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

    public AccountExpiredException(String msg, Throwable t) {
        super(msg, t);
    }
}
```

and JSON response is :

```
{
"timestamp":"2018-07-26T22:53:05.392+0000",
"status":401,
"error":"Unauthorized",
"message":"Unauthorized",
"path":"/login"
}
```

I get the same JSON response (401 error code) whenever the password is wrong or one of the methods of UserVO (which in turn implements UserDetails) return false :

```
boolean isAccountNonExpired();

boolean isAccountNonLocked();

boolean isCredentialsNonExpired();

boolean isEnabled();
```

So far so good.

When the user logs in and his/her password is expired I want to redirect the UI to a mandatory password change page. But how ? I always get the same JSON respons.

1) Since the JSON output that is returned is always a HTTP 401 error, how can I get a more fine grained response ? (How to tell client code that the password has expired?)

2) Is it generally considered good or bad practice to inform the user that his/her account is locked / expired / disabled ? (good user experience vs giving away info about account state to hackers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but I solved it by setting the "message" field :

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint, Serializable {

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

        String message = "Unauthorized";
        if ( authException instanceof BadCredentialsException )
            message = AUTH_CREDENTIALS_BAD;
        else if ( authException instanceof CredentialsExpiredException )
            message = AUTH_CREDENTIALS_EXPIRED;
        else if ( authException instanceof LockedException )
            message = AUTH_ACCOUNT_LOCKED;
        else if ( authException instanceof DisabledException )
            message = AUTH_ACCOUNT_DISABLED;
        else if ( authException instanceof AccountExpiredException )
            message = AUTH_ACCOUNT_EXPIRED;

        response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message );
    }
}
```

Now I get this as response :

```
{
   "timestamp":"2018-07-27T12:54:53.097+0000",
   "status":401,
   "error":"Unauthorized",
   "message":"credentials_expired",
   "path":"/login"
}
```